# Compare each index of 3 lists and extract the smallest value of the 3, for every element in the 3 lists

Tags: python, list

I have 3 lists of 1000 elements each. I want to compare the values of each index across all 3 lists, take the smallest value of the 3, and put all 1000 of the smallest values in another list.

I've tried comparing each and every element from 2 lists using a for loop, but the loop only extracted the first index's value.

Answer (score 1):

Without numpy:

```
newlist = [ min(a,b,c) for a,b,c in zip(list1,list2,list3) ]
```

You need to use `zip` to interleave the elements.

Answer (score 0):

With out using zip function.

```
#Assuming length of list1,list2,list3 are same

list1=[1,2,3,0]
list2=[2,0,1,10]
list3=[-1,-1,10,-20]   

print([ min(list1[i],list2[i],list3[i]) for i in range(len(list1))])
```